# Windows batch script unable to find the path for library through windows scheduler

Tags: batch-file

I have a java program which connects to my database and verify some reports and send out an email to the specific mail ids. And there is one batch script which calls this java class. This java class requires javax.activation.jar, javax_mail.jar, ojdbc14.jar which I Kept along with batch and java file in some folder.

When I run the program by executing the batch script directly from the path where it lies the program works and send out emails.

But now I have scheduled this batch script to run every one hour using the windows scheduler. At that point there is compilation error for my java saying unable to find the required dependent classes.

My batch file looks like this.

```
@echo off

cd D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL
D:

:: compile the Main class and helper classes
javac Constants.java
javac DBUtility.java
javac -cp ".;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" SendJobStatusEmail.java
javac -cp ".;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" JobReportScheduler.java


:: Run the Main class
java -cp ".;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" JobReportScheduler
```

If I remove the below lines from my batch its not able to run through the windows scheduler

```
cd D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL
D:
```

I want to remove these two lines. WHen the scheduler picks the batch file and executes it it should be able to pick the dpendent jars from lib folder under the directory where the batch stays.

It should not be dependent on the machine where, in which drive it it so that I can put in any windows machine and execute using windows scheduler.

I tried different options nothing works. PLease help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Replace `.` in your `CLASSPATH` with `D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL` if you just ran the compiled code. However, you compile the code each time the script runs, and these lines:

```
javac Constants.java
javac DBUtility.java
```

probably depend upon the current working directory being `D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL`, so I don't think you'll be able to get around changing into that directory (unless you modify your build process, e.g. by using `ant`).

Why do you want to avoid changing the directory anyway? If you're concerned about the working directory being different after the script runs, you could use `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`:

```
@echo off

pushd "D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL"
javac ...
...
java -cp ...
popd
```

but that doesn't really matter for a scheduled task.

And why do you want a scheduled task to re-compile your code over and over again in the first place?

---

**Actual solution:** Since the `javac` calls aren't present in the actual script, the code can be simplified to this:

```
@echo off

java -cp ".;.\lib\*" JobReportScheduler
```

when `D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL` is configured as the start directory of the scheduled task.

Comment: yeah i tried that. But it works only when you run the batch from the    D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL path. When I schedule from the windows scheduler it fails to get the path.

Comment: I dont need to recompile the classes. I have to remove those.  My intention is to remove hard coding. If i hard code this will force me to keep the file in one place. If I move this to another machine where no D drive available I have to change the path there.  Also I dont want to mention the jar file namesin the java command. If I keep them in a "lib" folder "D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL" through batch script I want to add everything in to class path say using a for loop(With for loop it worked on the command prompt, but failed when the batch script get invoked by the scheduler)

Comment: Then please show the *actual* code you want to run as a scheduled task. We're not playing guessing games here.

Comment: Appologies for the mistake from my side                            ` @echo off                                                    java -cp '.;lib \ *' JobReportScheduler`                            this should be my actual content of the batch script. there is lib folder where I place all the dpendent jars.

Comment: In that case try setting `D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL` as the start directory of your scheduled task (the field "Start in:") and make the command `java -cp ".;.\lib\*" JobReportScheduler`.

Comment: It worked when I set the Start in as "D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL". Now my batch file looks clean and neat. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL 
SET "Jpath=%cd%"

:: compile the Main class and helper classes
javac Constants.java
javac DBUtility.java
javac -cp "%Jpath%;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" SendJobStatusEmail.java
javac -cp "%Jpath%;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" JobReportScheduler.java


:: Run the Main class
java -cp "%Jpath%;javax.activation.jar;javax_mail.jar;ojdbc14.jar" JobReportScheduler
```

Comment: I dont want to hard code the path with D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL. It should be able to get the path from the batch script itself. I mean something like path=.;(which did not work from scheduler, but worked from command prompt if you go to D:\CPP\scheduler\JOB_REPORTS_MAIL and run it).  So that there is no hard coding.   If i hard code this will force me to keep the file in one place. If I move this to another machine where no D drive available i have to change there.